# .htaccess: redirect from older domain only index visitor but leave img/ css/ js/ files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using an old domain that points to the same server as a domain for images, css and js files so it improves download based on some advices (google and pingdom)

but i don't want visitors to browse my website with the old domain

so i want to keep (no DNS or any redirect) `oldDomain.com/css/style.css`

byt is soembody visits `oldDomain.com/items/345` or any urls excluding `img/` `css/` and `js/` shoudl be redirected to `newDomain.com`

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess of `oldDomain`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(img|css|js)/ http://newDomain.com}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R=301,L]
```